# Use EC2 for PDF Generation, provide public URL to user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have developed an application which allows Users to select multiple "transactions"; each of this is directly related to a PDF file.

When a User multi-selects them, and "prints" them, these PDF files are merged into one longer file to provide ease of print.

Currently, "transaction" PDFs are generated on request, and so is PDF-merging.

I'm trying to scale this up relaying over Amazon infrastructure, some questions arised to me.

1. Should I implement a queue for the PDF generation per "transaction"? If so, how can I provide the user a seamless experience? We don't want them to "wait"
2. Can I use EC2 to generate these PDF files for me? If so, can I provide a "public" link for the user to download the file directly from Amazon, instead of using our resources.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT ---- More details

1. User inputs some information through a regular form
2. System generates a PDF per request, using the provided information for the document
3. The PDF generated by the system is kept under Amazon S3
4. We provide an API which allows you to "print" multiple pdfs at once, to do so, we merge the selected PDF files from S3, into one file for ease-of-print
5. When you multi-print documents, a new window is opened which is your merged file directly, user needs to wait around 20ish seconds for it to display.
6. We can to leverage the resources used to generate the PDFs onto Amazon infrastructure, but we need to keep the same flow, meaning, we should provide an instant public link to the User to download & print the files.

Comment: Sounds a bit too broad of a question. Can you be a lot more specific? What's your code doing and what's the issues you're having at scale which you need to solve?

Comment: Just updated my question, thanks for your time!

Comment: Can't you just host the result in S3?

Comment: I'm using S3 as my cloud host at the moment for the whole project :) Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Based on your understanding, i think you just need your link to be created immediately right after user request for file. However, you want in parallel to create PDF merge. I have idea to do that based on my understanding, and may be it could work in your situations.

First start with some logic to create unique pdf file name, with random string representing name of file. And at same time in background generate PDF, but the name of PDF should be same as you created in first step. This will give user instant name of file with link to download. However, your file creation is still in progress.

Make sure, you use threads if using PHP or event loop if using Node.JS to run both steps at same time. This will avoid 404 error for file not found.

Transferring files from EC2 to S3 would also add latency delay. But if you want to preserve files for later or multiple use in future then S3 is good idea as it could simply serve PDF files for faster delivery. As we know S3 is used for static media storage. Otherwise simply compute everything and generate files on EC2

Comment: Ok, this is nice, because this is mostly what i've done. When you hit the API endpoint, you request a set of Work Order IDs.

Let's say 1, 2, 3. So I iterate each of these, and generate a temporary PDF file for each of these (this is necesarry because all of the documents have different headers, footers, page counters, designs, etc).

Then I collect these 3 generated files and merge them into one large PDF file. 

All files are stored in S3 and I'm returning the PDF content as direct download (with content-type headers)

Comment: Comment killed my styling, sorry. My question is, how to scale this? I'm using EC2 for now, and S3 for storage, but it's taking 20sec to process files, and if 10 clients hit it, it'll lag massively. I was reading and thought about using Load Balancer + EC2

Comment: Yes load balancer can work, but using threads will might solve issue.